# OGR SetAttributeFilter does not let datasource to update

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr

I am trying to update an attribute value for a certain feature in a shapefile. To filter out that feature, I use [SetAttributeFilter](https://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#acb2c6cc5fa3577df5be538284c1b0dde). This returns the feature I want, and [SetFeature](https://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#a6e7dfe0f900ac7fb0f457e7a49b3a5e3) also works as expected, but after running the code below *shapefile is not updated*.

My question is: how does [SetAttributeFilter](https://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#acb2c6cc5fa3577df5be538284c1b0dde) prevent shapefile from being updated with regular SetField -> [SetFeature](https://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#a6e7dfe0f900ac7fb0f457e7a49b3a5e3) method.

After commenting out a line with [SetAttributeFilter](https://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#acb2c6cc5fa3577df5be538284c1b0dde), shapefile gets updated (although the value is updated just for a first (`layer[0]`) feature).

```
from osgeo import ogr
shapefile = r"target_file.shp"
dataSource = ogr.Open(shapefile, 1)
layer = dataSource[0]

# This line is the source of the problem
layer.SetAttributeFilter("attr_a = 'a_value'")

feature = layer[0]
feature.SetField("attr_b", 999999)
layer.SetFeature(feature)
del dataSource
```